# linux/bash tips for developers?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Favourite command line trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625656/favourite-command-line-trick)
>   [useful linux commands for programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441115/useful-linux-commands-for-programmers)
>   [What is your single most favorite command-line trick using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash)

I have recently become accustomed to doing most of my development (in various languages) from the bash shell, using command-line tools and interfaces. I have discovered it is convenient to stay in the command line because you can do many things without leaving that interface, and it is fast.

What tools and tricks are you aware of that can make bash (perhaps in conjunction with an editor like `vim` or `emacs`) a more powerful development environment to work in?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625656/favourite-command-line-trick
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603696/linux-command-line-best-practices-and-tips
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441115/useful-linux-commands-for-programmers-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably done some or all of this, but for the record...

1. ctags/etags
2. plugins for vim and emacs
3. get to know the bash ! history substitution feature (but be careful! :-)
4. if using vi (over emacs) then get to know the :line mode
5. you might want to check out the [id-utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/) package
6. if using bash on windows via cygwin, use rxvt instead of the default dos box

You also want to set up each tool in the programmer mode. Editors like vi and emacs can autoindent, show matching parens, etc. You need to read the help and turns these things on. Be sure that you run bash in the history mode that matches your editing reflexes. It defaults to emacs but for vi one does `set -o vi`.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an X11 window manager that works well without needing a mouse.

- Awesome
- xmonad

After that:

1. screen
2. bash_completion
3. vim
4. cscope
5. ctags
6. remake

I rarely need to touch the mouse for anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, I use intensively [shortcuts](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html). Then, I could obviously mention things like `vim`, `grep`, `tail`, `head`, `find`, `sudo !!`,... But one thing I really can't live without is [Programmable Completion](http://www.caliban.org/bash/index.shtml#completion). Of course, this will depend on your habit, but here are some must have for me:

- [Ant Bash Completion](http://marius.scurtescu.com/2005/03/23/ant_bash_completion)
- [command line completion in GlassFish](http://blogs.oracle.com/harsha/entry/command_line_completion_in_glassfish)
- [Grails Bash Completion](http://www.grails.org/Grails+Bash+Completion) and/or [Autocomplete Grails Script Names in bash/zsh](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/03/25/autocomplete-grails-script-names-in-bashzsh/)
- [Maven Tab Auto Completion in Bash](http://willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=tabMaven)

Answer (score -1):

Oh let's see... cut, sort, grep, find