# In bash, what's the regular expression to list two types of files?

Tags: regex, bash

A directory contains `.zip` and `.rar` files, and files of other type.

To list only `.rar` and `.zip` files, there is `ls *.zip *.rar`

In bash, how to match both types with one regex?

Comment: technical nit: bash doesn't use regular expressions, it uses glob patterns. There are some important differences. In for former, `*` is a quantifier ("zero or more of the preceding pattern") but in glob it means "any characters".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you really want a regular expression?

This uses `*` ("[globbing](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)") and `{[...]}` ("[brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)").

```
$ ls *.{zip,rar}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash) for many, many more shortcuts.

Comment: `*.{zip,rar}` is a not regular expression?

Comment: @galath: not, it is not. It is called a "glob expression".

Comment: This does use brace expansion, and will produce an error if only one type of file is present, e.g. `ls: *.zip: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Phil: This is a good point. It said in the question that the "directory contains .zip and .rar files". so I figured that was okay.

Answer (score 12):

Use brace expansion:

```
ls *.{zip,rar}
```

If you must use a regex, you can use `find`:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(zip\|rar\)"
```

Answer (score 5):

In bash you can turn on the special **extglob** option to do this with a regex:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls *.*(zip|rar)
```

The advantage here is that it will list either or both file types, even if one is not present.

(As with all shell glob matching, the pattern will be passed directly to ls if there is no match; disable this behaviour with `shopt -s failglob`)

Comment: +1, but not that this causes `abc.ziprar`, `abc.zipzip` and so on to match.