# What is the unix history command "!$" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I'm trying to understand what is the unix command `!$`.

For example, I know that the command `!1` is used to run the history command number 1.

It seems like `!$` runs the last command typed in the bash.

For example if I wrote `mv folder12 folder123` and then I would write `cd !$` I would actually preform `cd folder123`.

Is it correct that `!$` runs the last command typed in the bash?

Comment: The command for repeating the previous command is `!!`, so it is unlikely that `!$` does this as well.

Comment: http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-history-cheat-sheet.pdf I have page 2 tacked onto my cube wall. Very handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!$` matches the last argument of the previous command.

From `man bash`

> yank-last-arg (M-., M-_)
>
> Insert  the last argument to the previous command (the last word of
>   the  previous  history  entry).   With  an  argument,  behave exactly 
>   like  yank-nth-arg.   Successive calls to yank-last-arg move back
>   through the history list, inserting the last  argument of each line in
>   turn.  **The history expansion facilities are used to extract the last
>   argument, as if the "!$"  history  expansion had been specified.**

#### Example

```
$ vi a
$ ls -l !$ # expands to "ls -l a"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 30 18 abr.  22:00 a
```

See also [What is your single most favorite command-line trick using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68496/1983854):

> I'm a fan of the !$, !^ and !* expandos, returning, from the most
>   recent submitted command line: the last item, first non-command item,
>   and all non-command items. To wit (Note that the shell prints out the
>   command first).

And also a good reading: [The Definitive Guide to Bash Command Line History](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/).

Comment: So to answer the last question, `!$` runs the last command only if it did not take any argument.

Comment: Though M-. might be a better one to learn if you have to pick just one. It copies the last argument of the previous command  for editing.

Comment: @EricRenouf If there was a single command with no argument, it will expand to that command. Try it.

Comment: True. If you do `ls` alone, `!$` will expand to that.