# How to run a command multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: linux, bash, command

Is it possible to run a command multiple times with different parameters?

Something like:

```
sudo apt-get install asd && install qwe && remove ert && autoremove && autoclean
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working from the command line, you can probably use the following: once you ran `command parameter1`, repeat `command` with `parameter2` instead typing:

```
^parameter1^parameter2
```

#### Example

I have two files: `a1` and `a2`. Let's `ls -l` the first:

```
$ ls -l a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 21 Apr 21 16:43 a1
```

Now let's do the same for `a2`:

```
$ ^a1^a2
ls -l a2                # bash indicates what is the command being executed
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 13 Apr 21 16:43 a2
```

You can find more tricks like this in [What is your single most favorite command-line trick using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68372/1983854).

Answer (score 12):

Use either a `for` loop:

```
for cmd in "install asd" \
        "install qwe" "remove ert" \
        "autoremove" "autoclean"
do
    sudo apt-get $cmd
done
```

or `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\n'  "install asd" \
    "install qwe"
    "remove ert"
    "autoremove"
    "autoclean" |
xargs -I "#" sudo apt-get "#"
```

Answer (score 3):

This loops a set of parameters and applies them to the same command.  There is no error checking, unlike in your example which will fail if one of the earlier commands fails

```
for param in asd qwe ert; do
    install $param
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, the shell cannot read your mind.

You could do something like this:

```
alias sag="sudo apt-get"
sag install asd qwe && sag remove ert && sag autoremove && sag autoclean
```

Although I'm not convinced that you really want `&&` there; you might be just as happy with `;`

Comment: never thought about setting alias but great idea :) thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the most general case, if you have a set or parameters you want to loop over, perhaps try

```
for first in one "two, with cinnamon" three; do
  for second in red yellow "odd color between brown and gray"; do
    for third in 0.1 0.5 1.0 2.0; do
        frobnicate --number "$first" --color "$second" --limit "$third"
    done
  done
done
```

or perhaps

```
while read -r first second third; do
  frobnicate --number "$first" --color "$second" --limit "$third"
done <<____EOF
  sixty-five   mauve    0.1
  sixty-five   crimson  0.1
  fifty-eleven lilac    0.2
  fifty-eleven lilac    0.5
  17           black    1.0
  42           black    1.0
____EOF
```

Just to spell this out, this will read three arguments from each line and run `frobnicate` with those as parameters. If this is for some sort of experiment, you would perhaps also like to redirect the results to a file named after the parameters, or perhaps add a fourth field to indicate the name of the file to write to?