# What is bang dollar (!$) in Bash?

Tags: bash, syntax, symbols

Bang dollar seems to refer to the last part of the last command line.

E.g.

```
$ ls -l
 .... something
$ !$
-l
bash: -l command not found
```

I can find plenty on the dollar variables (e.g. `$!`) but not on this. Any explanation?

Comment: `!` usually/often relates to the history commands.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/68496), It is the last argument of the previous command

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That's the last argument of the previous command. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators):

> `!!:$`
>
> designates the last argument of the preceding command. This may be shortened to `!$`.

**Remark.** If you want to play around with Bash's history, I suggest you turn on the shell option `histverify` like so:

```
shopt -s histverify
```

(you can also put it in your `.bashrc` to have it on permanently). When using history substitution, the substitution is not executed immediately; instead, it is put in readline's buffer, waiting for you to press enter… or not!

---

To make things precise, typing `!$` is not equivalent to typing `"$_"`: `!$` is really a *history substitution,* refering to the *last word of the previous command that was entered,* whereas `"$_"` is the last argument of the previously *executed* command. You can compare both (I have `shopt -s histverify`):

```
$ { echo zee; }
zee
$ echo "$_"
zee
$ { echo zee; }
zee
$ echo !$
$ echo }
```

Also:

```
$ if true; then echo one; else echo two; fi
one
$ echo "$_"
one
$ if true; then echo one; else echo two; fi
$ echo !$
$ echo fi
```

And also:

```
$ echo zee; echo "$_"
zee
zee
$ echo zee2; echo !$
$ echo zee2; echo "$_"
```

And also

```
$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
$ echo "$_"
3
$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
$ echo !$
$ echo {1..3}
```

And also

```
$ echo one ;
$ echo "$_"
one
$ echo one ;
one
$ echo !$
$ echo ;
```

There are lots of other examples, e.g., with aliases.

Comment: ^1 for the great examples.....so both share common funcs, but they r not the same.

Comment: @zee: indeed, they don't really play on the same level.

Comment: `++ ` for nice set of examples.

Comment: ... But work only in *interactive* mode!!:Compare `bash -c $'echo hello world\necho !$'` vs `bash -c $'echo hello world\necho $_'` ... *I have a "Happy", I have a "New year", han! "Happy new year!"*, @gniourf_gniourf!

Comment: @F.Hauri: of course, this is about _history expansion._

Answer (score 12):

`!$` can do what `$_` does, except the fact that `$_` does not store the value it returns (as its substitution) to `history`.

Here is an example.

With `!$`

```
za:tmep za$ ls -lad 
drwxr-xr-x  4 za  staff  136 Apr  6  2016 .
za:tmep za$ !$
-lad
-bash: -lad: command not found
za:tmep za$ history | tail -n 3
  660  ls -lad 
  661  -lad                     <<== history shows !$ substitution.  
  662  history | tail -n 3
```

With `$_`

```
za:tmep za$ ls -lad
drwxr-xr-x  4 za  staff  136 Apr  6  2016 .
za:tmep za$ $_
-bash: -lad: command not found
za:tmep za$ history | tail -n 3
  663  ls -lad
  664  $_         <<== history shows $_ and not its substitution. 
  665  history | tail -n 3
za:tmep za$
```

More options:

```
!^      first argument
!:2     second argument
!:2-$   second to last arguments
!:2*    second to last arguments
!:2-    second to next to last arguments
!:2-3   second to third arguments
!$      last argument
!*      all arguments
```

Comment: Technically, `!$` and `$_` are **not** the same. `!$` acts on a higher level. You can see the differences with aliases, or with compound commands, or with multiple commands. Compare `echo !$` with `echo $_` in the following cases: 1. `{ echo zee; }`; 2. `if true; then echo one; else echo two; fi`; 3. Also type two commands, e.g., `echo zee; echo $_` and `echo zee2; echo $!`.

Answer (score 1):

Monkey's answer:

whit !$ you can easily print the **last word** of the **previous command**

```
#Create new file
touch newfile.txt
#Edit new file using !$ instead newfile.txt again
nano !$
```